# STM32F103 UART button event delay slow

Tags: stm32, uart, hal

I'm testing very basic transmission with UART1 on my STM32F103C8T6 using CUBE MX and Keil v5.

I've prepared project in CUBE MX enabling UART and went to Keil.

All is working fine to be honest, if I press button on board (PA0), transmitted string changes correctly from stringa1 to stringa2, but it stays on stringa2 for 3 or 4 cycles even if I press and release the button very quickly.

It seems like a problem of synchronization or sort of timing, in shorts, even if button has been released, HAL is sending stringa2 like I have still my finger on button PA0.

What could be the problem?

```c
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */
    char *stringa1 = "ciao\r\n";
    char *stringa2 = "pressed\r\n";

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration----------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USART1_UART_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
      /*
        HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_13);
        HAL_Delay(500);
        HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_13);
        HAL_Delay(500);
      */

        if(HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_0)){
            HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, (uint8_t*) stringa1, strlen(stringa1), 10);
        } else {
            HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, (uint8_t*) stringa2, strlen(stringa2), 10);          
        }

        HAL_Delay(500);

  /* USER CODE END WHILE */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */

  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */

}
```

Comment: A you sure that the button has pull-up (external resistor or internal pullup)?

Comment: Thank you very much, was NOPULL, now with PULLUP is working like a charm. Can I ask you why? Was floating right? So in theory would be indefinite and send even inifite times the "pressed" state.

Comment: "floating" is not ideally floating. There are leakage currents that charge (or discharge -- depend on technology variations and temperature) input capacitance (input transistor gates, parasitic capacitance of traces, etc.). Button discharges the capacitance then leakage current charge it back to logic "1". This process can take seconds.

Comment: Thanks for your help